# Как убрать "сжатие" элементов меню?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, css-animation

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при наведении на один из элементов (в котором появляется padding), другие элементы оставались на своем месте и никак не изменялись в ширину. Как бы нужно убрать сжатие.
Пробовал с помощью `box-sizing: border-box`, но ничего не вышло.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.panel{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.main-menu {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu li a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #a69999;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: #f0e2e2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Testmonial</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Вместо этого используйте `transform: scale(1.05)` или около того)

Comment: это свойство увеличит текст, а мне этого не нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так вариант ?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-menu {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-menu li a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #a69999;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.main-menu li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.34s;
}

.main-menu li a:hover:after {
  top: -7px;
  left: -7px;
  right: -7px;
  bottom: -7px;
  background: #f0e2e2;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Testmonial</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div
```